# Should a method that simply delegates to a constructor be created?

Tags: object-oriented, api

For example, if I have a method

```
public void method(Pair<String, Object> pair){
    ...
}
```

Should I create the method

```
public void method(String str, Object obj){ this.method(new Pair<>(str, obj); }
```

if it is **not** to maintain an existing API? What are the considerations?

Comment: Sometimes I use convenience overloads like this.  It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have a look at the calling code. If it's frequently creating the pair just to call the method, you might want to add it. Are str and obj so closely related that a pair makes sense, or are they stored and used as pairs? Maybe removing the pair altogether is a good option. Important consideration: "Why does the existing method take a Pair?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is hiding the dependency on `Pair`, which may or may not be desirable.

To decide which one is better, you'd have to know what is more likely for the user of that method: to have a `Pair` object already constructed or to have its individual pieces, because that's when the difference between the two overloads will be significant.

If it's roughly equally likely to encounter both situations, it makes the most sense to have both versions of the method.

> if it is not to maintain an existing API?

Keep in mind that you are creating an API of your own here and consistency is important, too. A user of your API might get the impression that he can expect that overload to be present whenever a `Pair`  is necessary. Depending on how much you are using `Pair`  throughout your API, this might be a bit of work. And there *might be* maintenance necessary later.

Answer (score 1):

I always focus on how code is used. You'd like to go from using:

```
foo.method(new Pair(str, obj));
```

To using:

```
foo.method(str, obj);
```

To which I say: `foo` and `method` are terrible names!  At least I know what a `Pair` is.

By which I mean it would be a lot easier to see how good an idea this is if you'd use better names.  Method overloading is easy to go nuts with.  Best way I know to slow myself down is to stop and pick good meaningful names.  Two that spring to mind are:

```
foo.ofPair(new Pair(str, obj));

foo.put(str, obj);
```

Now if only I knew what this `foo` really was.

Comment: Presumably his example is illustrating that the names of the functions are not important in this context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to me they are.  I've gone down this rabbit hole before.  Ignoring the world around you so you can blindly follow a rule doesn't end well.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a convenience call-through. And I believe it's perfectly fine to have those. At least for the use-cases that are really needed over and over again.

Good convenience call-throughs significantly reduce the complexity of many calling sites while introducing virtually no additional complexity. After all, both are really the same function, they just want to have their parameters in a different format.

The only thing that you need to take care of, is that both overloads really make sense in and of themselves. If you have a call-through `void foo() { member.foo(); }`, this may not be justified if the action `foo` does not make sense for the containing class itself *even if most use-cases would actually call `container.member.foo()`*. The point is to keep the intent of the functions clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that spring to mind as considerations for this question being:

- Development standards
- Maintainability
- model accuracy

In the development phase your decision may set a precedence, and therefore standard, for the software development project.  That is, if you are going to follow a particular coding construct or pattern in one place then you "should" do it everywhere.  This may require going back through existing code base to implement the same pattern.  This consistency of standard will reduce the support burden.

The consideration in the maintenance phase requires you to form an opinion of the capability of the software maintenance team.  Which pattern will be more understandable by the support team?  Importantly, will it me understandable by you in the future.

Sometimes the choice of programming language construct is indicating that the object model has an error.  The example you provide implies to me that the parent class has a property that is a pair, and that the pair property owns the method.  When you change the object model the programming problem disappears.

Answer (score -1):

> For example, if I have a method
>   
>   `public void method(Pair<String, Object> pair){
>       ...
>   }`
>
> Should I create the method
>   
>   `public void method(String str, Object obj){ this.method(new Pair<>(str, obj); }`

No. Because now you have two functions, both called `method`, that do two different things. Instead, name the second function something like:

```
public void createPairFromComponentsThenMethod(String str, Object obj){
    this.method(new Pair<>(str, obj); 
}
```

Comment: I think this defeats overloading. I'd also say it's named completely wrong because the method primarily says how it's working, not what it does.

Comment: @Eiko, "I think this defeats overloading". That's sort of the point. Different methods, that take different parameters and that potentially do different things as a result, yet have the same names, doesn't sound like a sensible feature to me. I'll accept the name in this case does describe how, rather than what, but `method` doesn't give me much to go on :)

Comment: The only difference between the two functions in the OP is the way that they want their parameters served, there is zero functional difference. This is clear from how they are used to implement one another. From the outside view it's not even clear which is the call-through to the other, that's a pure implementation detail. Hence they *should* have the same name. Differentiating between the two by their names only reduces the readability of the code by introducing noise.

Comment: @cmaster I'm impressed. You worked all that out from "`method`"?

Comment: I worked that out from the implementation of the function that calls through to the other. The intent of the call-through is clear, the intent of the use of a `Pair<>` argument is also clear. And I've seen enough such call-throughs and come to appreciate their effect on the calling sites to immediately recognize the pattern. There is absolutely nothing obscure about the question except what `method()` is actually meant to do, but that is irrelevant to the question since it's an *abstract* example.

Comment: @cmaster oh, I'm disappointed now. You were just guessing. And in doing so, you ignore the fact that you know nothing of `Point`, or what the method does to it or what the consequences of having an overload create an instance will have on coupling etc etc. Naming stuff well is important because it forces you to stop and think about what the method is doing and convey that to the next developer. Or you can not bother and just call everything `method`...